# How to obtain raw body request in ogen SecurityHandler?

Tags: go, swagger, openapi

I use ogen (https://github.com/ogen-go/ogen/) to generate handler from my openapi spec. I also want to use security for my api endpoints, so now I have next method:

```
func (s SecurityHandler) Handle(ctx context.Context, operationName string, t gen.APIHeader) (context.Context, error) {
    if !m.env.Application.LocalMode {
        if err := VerifyWebhook(t.APIKey, nil, SECRET_KEY); err != nil {
            return ctx, err
        }
    }
    return ctx, nil
}
```

To verify webhook, I need to obtain raw request body, but I don't see any way to do it now... Probably, the middleware is a good alternative, but maybe I still can use SecurityHandler?